# Ubuntu 12.04; Internet connection established, but no access

Tags: 12.04, internet, lan

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I am unable to do it, even though I've read through a lot of answered questions on this site.

I got a netbook with Ubuntu 12.04 on it. After plugging in the Internet cable, the computer tells me that the connection is established.

After clicking the Firefox logo, there appears an error site of my internet provider. **This happens, because I didn't type in my user name and password.** Now where can I type them in so the computer lets me browse the Internet?

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to provide more details to get an answer. Those of us reading this need to know what the error says, if you get an error, but, in this case, this is not an ubuntu specific issue, and so it is probably not appropriate to ask it here. Your ISP's technical support should help you. It sounds like your computer is obtaining an IP address and attempting to retrieve HTTP data successfully. Overcoming the obstructions put in place by your ISP are something that ubuntu expertise will not help resolve. Contact your ISPs technical support and make them earn their keep.
Good luck!

Comment: Maybe a screenshot can help to understand your question.

Comment: do you have a liveCD, or usb ? try booting with it and open firefox from there

Comment: Where do you normally type in the username and password for Internet connection? Please update your original question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go to the IP address of your modem/router. Look on the back of the thing that your phone line goes into for an IP adress, username and password. Usually something like:

192.168.0.1
admin
password

Open Firefox, type the IP address into the URL bar and then look for a place to enter your ISP username and password. This isn't really an Ubuntu related question, I don't think, but I may have misread it. Screenshots might help :)